# Fermat´s two squares theorem for primes p=1 (mod 3)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was looking at a recent problem, that $p=1$ (mod 3) implies that there are natural numbers x and y so that $p=x^2+xy+y^2$.

The proof given is complicated.
I was looking for a simpler proof (haven't found it yet) and looked at a subgroup, p=1 (mod 12). For these primes, we also have Fermat´s theorem that $p=a^2+b^2 $.

I was therefore looking at $p=x^2+xy+y^2=a^2+b^2$ and found that for some low primes, either x or y is a factor of either a or b. 
Do you know if this holds for all such primes?

Comment: $181$ has $11,4$ and $10,9$

Comment: A poor conjecture. Thanks.